# Why won't FR3DLdap work?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fr3dldapbundle

I'm running symfony 2.2 and trying to install FR3DLdap (2.0.x-dev, but tried others) as per the documentation. Upon clearing the cache I get a 'Unrecognized options "client" under "fr3d_ldap".

My config.yml: (indentation is right; Didn't know how to preserve it for YAML here)

```
fr3d_ldap:
client:
    host:         my.host.name
#   port:         389    # Optional
#   version:        3    # Optional
    username:     portaladmin    # Optional
    password:     mypassword    # Optional
#   optReferrals: false  # Optional
#   useSsl:       true   # Enable SSL negotiation. Optional
    useStartTls:  true   # Enable TLS negotiation. Optional
user:
    #baseDn: ou=users, dc=host, dc=foo
    baseDn: DC=rjis, DC=co, DC=uk
    filter: (&(ObjectClass=Person))
    attributes:          # Specify ldap attributes mapping [ldap attribute, user object method]
        - { ldap_attr: uid,  user_method: setUsername } # Default
#       - { ldap_attr: cn,   user_method: setName }     # Optional
#       - { ldap_attr: ...,  user_method: ... }         # Optional
#service:
#   user_manager: fos_user.user_manager          # Overrides default user manager
#   ldap_manager: fr3d_ldap.ldap_manager.default # Overrides default ldap manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.0.x branch `client` key has been renamed as `driver`

https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/2.0.x/Resources/doc/index.md#4-configure-configyml

Comment: Not exactly sure how I missed that. Thanks, Maks3w.